# In Shia religion, in salat can we give three shadah?

Tags: salat, shiism

In Salat while sitting can we give three shadah? As one of my friends told me about that it makes salah as BAATIL (invalid) my reciting "ALI UN WALI ULLAH" in salat... I have searched and heard many scholar, but I am not clear of this? If any one can help by giving some authentic references?

Comment: Why do you refer to Shia as a religion? Do you not consider it part of the religion of Islam?

Answer (score 2):

> In Shia religion, in salat can we give three shadah?

Although, the phrase of "ALI UN WALI ULLAH" is considered as a significant phrase/belief for Shia Islam, but, to the best of my knowledge, it is recited (only) in Adan/Aqamah of Salah of Shia (as a Mustahab practice/Dua); and (AFAIK) Shia Islam doesn't regard/allow it among the wajib (obligatory) parts of Salah, such as in Tashahod, etc.

Reference: [hawzah.net](https://hawzah.net/fa/Question/View/62585/%D8%B0%DA%A9%D8%B1-%D8%A7%D8%B4%D9%87%D8%AF-%D8%A7%D9%86-%D8%B9%D9%84%DB%8C%D8%A7-%D9%88%D9%84%DB%8C-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%84%D9%87-%D9%88-%D8%AA%D8%B4%D9%87%D8%AF-%D9%86%D9%85%D8%A7%D8%B2)